# unable to synchronize two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

If I do:

ConsoleApp1:

```
    bool mutexCreated;
    var mutex = new Mutex(true, "MemoryMappedFileMutex", out mutexCreated);

    Console.Write("Run Console App2 then press enter");
    Console.Read();

    // do work
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    mutex.ReleaseMutex(); // makes console app 2 to stop waiting
```

ConsoleApp2

```
    var mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("MemoryMappedFileMutex");

    mutex.WaitOne();

    // continue executing once console app 1 releases mutex
```

Everything works great. I have to start consoleApp1 first for this algorithm to work though.

**Now my qestion is** I will like consoleApp2 to act as the server. Therefore I will like to start that application first. The problem is that if I do:

```
    bool mutexCreated;
    var mutex = new Mutex(true, "MemoryMappedFileMutex", out mutexCreated);

    mutex.WaitOne();  // <------ mutex will not wait why????
```

if I do `mutex.WaitOne()` that thread will not wait. In other words I want to start consoleApp2 first and have that application wait until I signal the mutex somehow on console application 1....

Comment: Don't call your mutex "MemoryMappedFileMutex". Mutex names are global. You risk colliding with some other program using that common name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server app, try calling the constructor with false as the first parameter, so that the calling thread will not own the mutex initially.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting on a Mutex from the owning thread does not block, and you specified true as the first Mutex constructor arg, which indicates it gets created already owned by the current thread.